# how to use securesocial in play 2.3.0

Tags: scala, playframework

From the home page of SecureSocial, it said

SecureSocial for Play 2.3.x is built from master

Then what should I put in the library dependency?

e.g for 2.1.3 I could use the following

"ws.securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "2.1.3",

Should I use the following or something else?

"ws.securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "**snapshot**",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots")` to your resolvers and use [the following dependency](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/ws/securesocial/securesocial_2.11/master-SNAPSHOT/):

```
"ws.securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "master-SNAPSHOT"
```

Note though that the changes in SecureSocial for Play 2.3 are extensive and still mostly undocumented, so adapting existing code is going to be a slog.

Comment: thanks, do you know when will play 2.3 officially supported in securesocial?

Comment: No, I've only ever used SecureSocial for one project and haven't been following development closely. You're probably best off asking the mailing list.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more how do you add it to the resolver? I tried to add resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots") after the typesafe repsitory resolver (used by default) (with a blank line) but I still have an error unresolved dependency... (Sorry for the dumb question.)

Comment: I also tried this : resolvers += "snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/ws/securesocial/securesocial_2.11/master-SNAPSHOT/" to follow the same syntax than the documentation but without success.